# Regex search with whitespace in Solr

Tags: solr, solr6

I Have imported a csv file which contains a field "Address" having multiple words with spaces in between"  e.g. Address contains "23 delhi ST KANGAROO POINT", "23/50 BANGALORE ST KANGAROO POINT"  etc.

I want to search with "23", "23 del", "23/50" , "23/50 banga"  etc. 
In managed.schema file, I have added

```
<field name="Address" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
<field name="Suburb" type="text_general" indexed="true"    stored="true"/>
<field name="StreetNo" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
<field name="HouseNo" type="text_general" indexed="false" stored="false"/>
```

where Suburb, StreetNo, HouseNo are other fields. 
I am able to search with "23" "del" etc. but it not with spaces in between.
I am using Solr6.4.

I am using the default text_general type configuration.

```
<fieldType name="text_general" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
   <analyzer type="index">
        <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory" />
        <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords.txt" />           
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory" />
   </analyzer>
   <analyzer type="query">
        <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory" />
        <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords.txt" />
        <filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" synonyms="synonyms.txt" ignoreCase="true" expand="true" />
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory" />
    </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

Moreover, After changing the schema, do I need to re import the csv file or everything will be taken care automatically ?

Comment: I am using the default text_general type configuration

Comment: Please add in your question one or more regex query you did in your example.

Comment: And add a sample of CSV you've loaded into Solr.